# PostgreSQL slow query

Tags: postgresql, openvas

Having OpenVAS (backed by PostgreSQL) instance that is slow when opening 'Tasks' tab.

Following query runs 22 seconds in PostgreSQL. Any suggestions how this can be optimized?

```
SELECT id, host,
       iso_time (start_time), iso_time (end_time),
       current_port, max_port, report,
       (SELECT uuid FROM reports WHERE id = report),
       (SELECT uuid FROM hosts
        WHERE id = (SELECT host FROM host_identifiers
                    WHERE source_type = 'Report Host'
                      AND name = 'ip'
                      AND source_id = (SELECT uuid FROM reports
                                       WHERE id = report)
                      AND value = report_hosts.host
                    LIMIT 1)
       )
FROM report_hosts
WHERE report = 702;
```

The plan is

```
 Index Scan using report_hosts_by_report on report_hosts  (cost=0.42..1975570.99 rows=447 width=38) (actual time=50.042..22979.257 rows=1206 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (report = 702)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Index Scan using reports_pkey on reports  (cost=0.28..2.49 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1206)
           Index Cond: (id = report_hosts.report)
   SubPlan 4
     ->  Index Scan using hosts_pkey on hosts  (cost=4414.37..4416.59 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1206)
           Index Cond: (id = $4)
           InitPlan 3 (returns $4)
             ->  Limit  (cost=2.49..4414.09 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=18.998..18.998 rows=0 loops=1206)
                   InitPlan 2 (returns $2)
                     ->  Index Scan using reports_pkey on reports reports_1  (cost=0.28..2.49 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1206)
                           Index Cond: (id = report_hosts.report)
                   ->  Seq Scan on host_identifiers  (cost=0.00..4411.60 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=18.997..18.997 rows=0 loops=1206)
                         Filter: ((source_type = 'Report Host'::text) AND (name = 'ip'::text) AND (source_id = $2) AND (value = report_hosts.host))
                         Rows Removed by Filter: 99459
 Planning time: 0.531 ms
 Execution time: 22979.575 ms
```

Comment: Scalar subqueries, why? (including LIMIT 1 without ORDER BY;  why?)

Comment: The query hardcoded into the OpenVAS, so I'm not aware why they (i.e. OpenVAS developers) did that this way. Also suspect that I can't change the query itself, but can optimize the database side (smarter indexes?). I did the general postgresql tuning for this machine (32cores, SSD, 32G RAM), but it still slow.

Comment: In the plan 3rd row from the bottom says Sequential scan on host_identifiers, does it mean it lacks an index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the time is spent in the 1206 sequential scans of `host_identifiers`.

Try to replace the subqueries with joins:

```
SELECT rh.id, rh.host,
       iso_time(rh.start_time), iso_time(rh.end_time),
       rh.current_port, rh.max_port, rh.report,
       r.uuid,
       h.uuid
FROM report_hosts AS rh
   LEFT JOIN reports AS r
      ON rh.report = r.id
   LEFT JOIN host_identifiers AS hi
      ON hi.source_id = r.uuid
         AND hi.value = rh.host
         AND hi.source_type = 'Report Host'
         AND hi.name = 'ip'
   LEFT JOIN hosts AS h
      ON h.id = hi.host
WHERE rh.report = 702;
```

This is not exactly the same because it does not account for the `LIMIT 1` that makes little sense without an `ORDER BY`, but it should be close to the truth.

Proper indexes will make it fast (if they don't yet exist):

- one on `reports(id)`
- one on `host_identifiers(source_id, value)`
- one on `hosts(id)`

Your query is hard to read because you don't qualify the columns with the table name.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! Adding index `host_identifiers(source_id, value)` is exactly what I was looking for:

```
create INDEX host_identifiers_source_id_value on host_identifiers(source_id, value);
```

Page load time for 'Tasks' tab decreased from 70s to *just* 13s.

Thanks!